# Show the responce of ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to replace the table->tr->**td** with new **td** I have tried like this but it is not working.

```
<table id="job1">
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr id="Jobstatus1"> 
    <td>Accept</td>
    <td>Reject</td>
  <tr> 
</table>


<table id="job2">
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr id="Jobstatus2"> 
    <td>Accept</td>
    <td>Reject</td>
  <tr> 
</table>
```

I am showing a response like this:

```
$response['jobStatus'] = 
'<td class="textcenter" colspan="2" style="color:green;" > Accepted The Above Job </td>';
```

This is what I am trying in ajax response:

```
if (response["success"] == true){
$("#Jobstatus"+jobId).remove();  //in here jobId will come as 1,2....
$("#Jobstatus"+jobId).append($response['jobStatus']);
```

Comment: `jobId` is coming fine i can see that in console..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.remove()` method will remove the element so `append()` can't find it, you should use `.htmt('')` or `.empty()` instead of remove.

**Replace :**

```
$("#Jobstatus"+jobId).remove();
```

**By :**

```
$("#Jobstatus"+jobId).html('');
//Or
$("#Jobstatus"+jobId).empty();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried this but not working is there any thing else possible or do i need to call from parent table..?

Comment: Try `console.log(jobId, $response['jobStatus'])` to see if the response is really what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `html()` method to inject the response value straight into the target `tr` element, replacing whatever it contained:

```
$("#Jobstatus" + jobId).html($response['jobStatus']);
```